# python: what if add a underscore in the parameters in the def function

Tags: python-3.x, function, interpreter

My friend wrote a function like this but got stuck. I don't know why it was stuck...I searched that "_" means I don't care, but what does it mean, if I used it in the function parameters `_params`?

```
def calc(_params):
    if _params > 0:
        _params -= 1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = 1
    while params > 0:
        calc(params)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code you made here essentially runs a function that passes the value of `params` as 1 to a function which updates the value of a local variable named `_params` inside the function and no change occurs to the variable named `params` which you initially declared as 1.

> No problem regarding the name _params

Comment: sure, so why does ```_params``` not updated?

Comment: `params` and `_params` are completly different variables. Changing one doesn't change second. `_` doesn't have special meaning in python, `__` is.